# Totaling a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, gridview

In one of my ASP.NET Web Applications, I am using a [BulkEditGridView](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattdotson/articles/490868.aspx) (a GridView which allows all rows to be edited at the same time) to implement an order form. In my grid, I have a column which calculates the total for each item (cost x quantity) and a grand total field at the bottom of the page. Currently, however, these fields are only refreshed on every post-back. I need to have these fields updated dynamically so that as users change quantities, the totals and grand total update to reflect the new values. I have attempted to use AJAX solutions to accomplish this, but the asynchronous post-backs interfere with the focus on the page. I imagine that a purely client-side solution exists, and I'm hopeful that someone in the community can share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your calculations can be reproduced in JavaScript the easiest method would be using jQuery to get all the items like this:

```
$("#myGridView input[type='text']").each(function(){
  this.change(function(){
    updateTotal(this.value);
  });
});
```

Or if your calculations are way too complex to be done in JavaScript (or time restraints prevent it) then an AJAX call to a web service is the best way. Lets say we've got our webservice like this:

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public int UpdateTotal(int currTotal, int changedValue){
  // do stuff, then return
}
```

You'll need some JavaScript to invoke the webservice, you can do it either with jQuery or MS AJAX. I'll show a combo of both, just for fun:

```
$("#myGridView input[type='text']").each(function(){
  this.change(function(){
    Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke(
      "/Helpers.asmx",
      "UpdateTotal",
      false,
      { currTotal: $get('totalField').innerHTML, changedValue: this.value },
      showNewTotal
    );
  });
});

function showNewTotal(res){
  $get('totalField').innerHTML = res;
}
```

Check out this link for full info on the Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke method: http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys.Net/WebServiceProxyClass/WebServiceProxyInvokeMethod.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to build some javascript in you RowDataBound method to constantly update those totals when the textboxes change.

So during the RowDataBound, start building a javascript string in memory that will add up the textboxes you need added. What's nice in RowDataBound is you can get the Client Side id's of these textboxes by calling TextBox.ClientId.
Add this javascript to the page, then also add an onkeyup event to each textbox you require to call this script.

So something like (this is a row bound event from a gridview)

```
private string _jscript;
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      //Get your textbox
      Textbox tb = e.Row.FindControl("tbAddUp");
      //Add the event that you're going to call to this textbox's attributes
      tb.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "MyAddUpJavaScriptMethod();");
      //Build the javascript for the MyAddUpJavaScriptMethod
      jscript += "document.getElementById('" + tb.ClientId + '").value + ";
   }
}
```

Then once you've built that whole script, use your Page.ClientScript class to add a method to you page which will be called by your onkeyup in your textboxes "MyAddUpJavaScriptMethod"

Hope that makes sense and helps